# Formula to return value if all non-empty values are same, else return empty?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, distinct-values

I have a Google Sheet with many (many, many) cases of the following situation:

```
  A    B    C    D    E
1 a    b1             e1
2 a                   
3      b2        d    e2
4 a                   e2
```

Basically each row lists content (information about research papers) scraped from a different location; theoretically, the values in each row should be the same, but since some locations lacked some information, and sometimes the information differs in some minor (but possibly important) way, there isn't 100% agreement throughout.

I'd like for each cell below such a group to display one value if all the non-empty values in that column are the same and to display nothing at all if there's some disparity between the non-empty values. See row 5 below:

```
  A    B    C    D    E
1 a    b1             e1
2 a                   
3      b2        d    e2
4 a                   e2

5 a              d
```

This is basically a first programmatical clean-up to assist further manual labor (which is unavoidable).

There's an example sheet [available here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XKyxNCtn-ZqiQ2qRsU4RDMbEw8DR8uSkSDqEsAhvsbg) - the real thing would have about 18 sets of values (title, authors, ISBN, publication, URL, keywords, etc), and 270 columns (each for another publication). The orange rows at the bottom are just pasted in manually but show the values I would like to get in the blue rows via formulas.

I realize this can be done with a massive string of IFs, but... surely there must be a way to write a formula that will extract all the non-empty values from an array or group of cells, compare them with each other, and return a single value if they're all equal?

Unfortunately, I'm drawing a blank...

Comment: Would you please share a copy of your spreadsheet. Your explanation of how the data is presented and the logic to be applied to develop a  successful outcome is lacking. You've described "many, many, etc" cases but you haven't described how they are laid out in your spreadsheet; whether each case is a separate sheet, whether there are multiple spreadsheets and multiple sheets, whether there are many rows and each "group" is separated by a blank row; whether the solution is to be inserted into "the" blank row; whether a new blank row is required.

Comment: @Tedinoz Hope the spreadsheet example I added as a link works as an explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(IF(COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B5, B2:B5<>"", B2:B5<>"#N/A")))>1, ,
 UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B5, B2:B5<>"", B2:B5<>"#N/A"))))
```

[image: 0]

or shorter:

```
=IF(COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER(D2:D5, D2:D5<>"", D2:D5<>"#N/A"))>1, ,
 UNIQUE(FILTER(D2:D5, D2:D5<>"", D2:D5<>"#N/A")))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is surely not an optimal solution but it works

`=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A7,first_non_empty_cell)=COUNTA(A1:A7),first_non_empty_cell,"")`

You might consider replacing `first_non_empty_cell` with
`LOWER(INDEX(A1:A7,MATCH(1,INDEX((A1:A7<>0),0),0)))` 
or with the cell containing the value you want to use for comparisons.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work...? It always seems to return an empty value.

Answer (score 1):

Countunique should work:

```
=if(countunique(A1:A4)=1,sortn(A1:A4,1),"")
```

I've used sortn because I want to remove any empty cells from the list of values before displaying what should be the single non-empty value and that is one way of doing it (empty cells are sorted to the end so won't appear).

[image]

**Edit**

If the data includes #N/A's probably the shortest way to deal with them would be to use the (to me slightly obscure) function countuniqueifs

```
=if(countuniqueifs(A1:A4,A1:A4,"<>#N/A")=1,sortn(A1:A4,1),"")
```

Blank cells and #N/A's are still sorted after everything else, so I think the sortn part should still be valid.

[image]

But there is a further issue with this - if the range contains empty strings returned from a formula, the sortn part won't work properly, so would have to fall back on filtering:

```
=if(countuniqueifs(C1:C4,C1:C4,"<>#N/A",C1:C4,"<>")=1,filter(C1:C4,C1:C4<>"#N/A",C1:C4<>""),"")
```

Comment: This is more elegant than the solution I've accepted, but it doesn't seem to handle potential #N/As amongst the values (which I realized post factum would be a nice perk). However, I'll likely end up using this approach in the future where I can get away with a simpler formula. Thanks!

Comment: I hadn't realised until now that there is a countuniqueifs which could deal with #N/A's - will add to my answer.